# Store predefined variable and retrieve in a text box using js and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button in HTML and gave link to the form. I need when I click on button the value automatically show in a text box.

```
<script>
   var textToFind = "{{ product.title }}"; 

   var dd = document.getElementById('ContactFormProduct');

   for (var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
   if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
        dd.selectedIndex = i;
         break;
}
```

Comment: Is it the code you wrote for?

Comment: show your html code!!!

Comment: you mean button or select with option?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understoond u well:

```js
function showText() {
var text="bla bla";
document.getElementById('text').value=text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showText()">click me</button>
<input id="text"/>
```

If you want to show `input` only after click

```js
function showText() {
var text="bla bla";
var input=document.getElementById('text');
input.value=text;
input.style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showText()">click me</button>
<input id="text" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: Tell me if you need help

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but dats not what i want.

Comment: so explain what you want and edit question I cant guess what u want

Comment: problem is:- I have created wholesale page for my portal, in this page i have display lots of product. and i have attached " get a quotation" button. when customer fill quotation button... product name fill automatically.

Comment: Dear sir, i am working with shopify software. here my code for button 
         <a href="https://store.technotrade.in/pages/contact-supplier"  class="btn btn-default"  >Get a Quotation</a>